# How to pass Frame of UIView from One screen to Another when Copy-Paste views?

Tags: swift, uiview, frame, deep-copy

I'm copying `UIView` from ***one screen to Another***. By using below code I'm able to copy View with it's **visible appearance**, only problem is I'm **unable to get first view's frame**.

- Copy view code

```
extension UIView{
    func copyView() -> AnyObject{
        return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: self))! as AnyObject
    }
}
```

- Screen presentation code of **First Screen**

```
 if let vc = Router.filterPopup.instance as? FilterOptionPopUpVC {
    vc.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
    vc.viewCpy = self.btnSignIn?.copyView() as! UIView  // Here I'm copying the view
    vc.viewCpy.frame = self.btnSignIn?.frame ?? CGRect()   // Also tried to copy the frame of first view

    print("Frame number 1:- \(self.btnSignIn?.frame ?? CGRect())")
    self.navigationController?.present(vc, animated: true)
 }
```

- Second screen, where am adding copied **view as a `subView`**.

```
    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

        DispatchQueue.main.async { [self] in
            copyView?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            
            print("Frame number 2:- \(viewCpy.frame )") //Here I'm checking copied view's frame
            
            copyView?.addConstraints([
                NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.copyView ?? UIView(), attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.viewCpy, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0.0000),
                NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.copyView ?? UIView(), attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.viewCpy, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0.0000),
                NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.copyView ?? UIView(), attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.viewCpy, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0.00000),
                NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.copyView ?? UIView(), attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.viewCpy, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0.00000),
                NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.copyView ?? UIView(), attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.viewCpy, attribute: .width, multiplier: 1, constant: 0.00000),
                NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.copyView ?? UIView(), attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.viewCpy, attribute: .height, multiplier: 1, constant: 0.00000)
            ])

  
            copyView?.addSubview(self.viewCpy)
            self.copyView?.layoutIfNeeded()
            self.copyView?.layoutSubviews()
        }
    }
```

- Getting both frames different from each other

```
Frame number 1:- (24.0, 498.33333333333337, 327.0, 56.0)
Frame number 2:- (0.0, 0.0, 44.0, 56.0)
```

Comment: Yes, I believe the behavior is right. It copy the actual view.. 44x56 is the actual view height in the storyboard which you copied.. then using constraint you give the frame for the view... I think better you convert your function to return view,frame using which you can give size in the new view...

Comment: @FahimParkar reference please

Comment: @steveSarsawa - This can be a very unreliable approach, and is not recommended. A far better option is to define the properties you want to copy and, in your destination controller, re-create the object. However, if your Archive/UnArchive approach is working well enough for you... We need to see more of your code. Likely, somewhere before `print("Frame number 2:...)` you have set `self.viewCpy.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`